# Problem regarding jQuery Lightbox and mod_rewrite

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mod-rewrite

I'm facing a big problem with jQuery Lightbox effect and mod_rewrite.

When trying to fire any image from one of my url that has been rewritten, it shows a black box. Then the image everything else shows up at the end of the page and it doesn't fire a popup. Even the close page doesn't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may be because of missing light-box CSS file. 
you need to check out if light-box css is not included then please include it and then try again.

Thanks.